# Why is 23 equal to 10111 in binary?

Tags: javascript, binary

I've tried to convert 23 to binary and came up with the number `100111` by using [the following process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/converting-decimalbase-10-numbers-to-binary-by-repeatedly-dividing-by-2/86211#86211):

```
1) 23 = 22 + 1 // find out the least significant bit 1
2) 22/2 = 10 + 1 // next bit is 1
3) 10/2 = 4 + 1 // next bit is 1
4) 4/2 = 2 + 0 // next bit is 0
```

So I'm left with the 2 in decimal, which is 10 in binary. Now I'm writing down the number:

10 plus the the bits from the operations 4, 3, 2, 1 gives me
`100111`, however, the answer is `10111`. Where is my mistake?

Comment: It doesn't sounds like a programming question.

Comment: Last I checked, `10/2 = 5`...

Comment: This is a really bizarre way to count binary...

Comment: Agree with @ndugger. If I were you, I would subtract the largest binary each iteration until you reach 0. That would give you the binary representation.

Comment: `10111 = (16 * 1) + (8 * 0) + (4 * 1) + (2 * 1) + (1 * 1) = 23`

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary) for one of multiple ways, that is not so wierd as yours (for decimal conversion to binary).

Comment: @ndugger, check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/86211/333066) explanation

Comment: @timolawl, can you please point me the algorithm you're describing?

Comment: Well it would appear your method is fine. It's just that you have some arithmetic errors. For instance, 22/11 is 11 not 10 + remainder 1. Similarly, 10/2 is 5 with no remainder. The method I've described is the second one from this [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary).

Comment: @timolawl, those are not remainders, I incorrectly specified them as such, those are bits near the 2^0 column

Comment: @Maximus yes they're the bits, but they're remainders as well as mentioned in the link you provided. `Lather, rinse, and repeat until the remainder quotient is 0.` I'll add an answer with your method. Give me a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided with [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/converting-decimalbase-10-numbers-to-binary-by-repeatedly-dividing-by-2/86211#86211), the binary representation of the decimal number `23` is as follows:

```
ex:  Convert 23 to a binary representation

23 / 2 = 11 R 1
11 / 2 = 5  R 1 
5  / 2 = 2  R 1
2  / 2 = 1  R 0
1  / 2 = 0  R 1

answer = 10111
```

As you currently have it,

> 1) 23 = 22 + 1 // find out the least significant bit 1

This step is unnecessary. You don't need to shave off the odd number first. Simply follow the procedure outlined in the link to generate the output. What this means is that the only operation you perform on your decimal number output is repeated divisions by `2`, with the remainders spelling out your binary representation of your number.

---

If this isn't a programming question, it should be migrated to the correct forum.

If you do want a JavaScript solution as well, since you have marked this question with the JavaScript tag, then the easiest way is to simply do `(N).toString(2)`, where `(N)` is your decimal number and `.toString(2)` converts your number to a binary representation of your number in string form. The `2` represents the radix/base.

Comment: thanks, but _This step is not correct._ is correct), because I'm simply representing here 23 as `(x(n)*2^n+...+x(1)*2^(1)) + 1*2^0`, where the part `(x(n)*2^n+...+x(1)*2^(1))` represents 22. Then I'm dividing this part by 2 to get another coefficient near the 2^0.

Comment: That's fine, but you have to understand that the shaved off `1` needs to be incorporated back into the final result. Following the example in the link, it means `10110` + `00001` which is `10111`.

Comment: Please see my [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1769870/333066) to the question

Answer (score 1):

In the end, what you want to get is

```
23 = 16 + 4 + 2 + 1 
   = 1*16 + 0*8 + 1*4 + 1*2 + 1*1
   = 1*2^4 + 0*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0
```

The calculations should look like this:

```
23 = 2*11 + 1 (1st least significant digit is 1)
11 = 2*5  + 1 (2nd least significant digit is 1)
5  = 2*2  + 1 (3rd least significant digit is 1)
2  = 2*1  + 0 (4th least significant digit is 0)
1  = 2*0  + 1 (5th least significant digit is 1)
```

Comment: thansk, I'm using this the algorithm explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/86211/333066). Can you please elaborate how your calculations are in line with this algorithm?

Comment: The basic idea of what I am doing is that the base-b representation of `N` is equal to the base-b repreentation of `N/b` followed by a last digit, which is `N % b`

Comment: thanks, based on my [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1769870/333066) exploration the fifth step is unnecessary, since we can take two bits `1` and `0` from this expression `2*1 + 0`.

Comment: I prefer not having to "special case" the last step. It results in a simpler algorithm :)

Comment: yeah, I've decided to stick to that approach too. Thanks for your contribution)